# Allow SSRS report to scroll to the bottom without automatically paging

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report that renders multiple pages. A page does not fit on the screen, so the user has to scroll to see all of the data on said page. As the user scrolls towards the bottom of the page, the report automatically advances to the next page of the report (at about the time the bottom of the page reaches the bottom of the screen). Is there a way to only allow the report to advance to the next page via the paging buttons?

Comment: which control are you using to render the report?